# Relating Firebase Auth users with Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an login app for users. But I add email and password from firebase console.
And I have another app for admin users where I can add the user info and details.

I'm adding names etc but I'am also adding the Uid from Firebase Auth so I am hoping to link these.
I just have a `LoginActivity` and a `MainActivity` in the User app. When the user get the credentials from admin they can log in and they get to `MainActivity`. It's in the users `MainActivity` I want to get the stored data for the current user that was stored in firebase database from the admin app.

Also I have added both the user app and the admin app in Firebase.

Can someone help me?

UserApp
LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etuseremail, etuserpassword;
    Button btnloginuser;
    TextView tvforgotpassword;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_user);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        etuseremail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_userloginemail);
        etuserpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_userloginpassword);

        btnloginuser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_loginuser);
        tvforgotpassword = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_forgotpassword);

        btnloginuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginuser();

            }
        });

        tvforgotpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });



        }

    private void loginuser() {

        String email = etuseremail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = etuserpassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            etuseremail.setError("Epost addresse mangler");
            etuseremail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            etuseremail.setError("Bruk en gyldig epost addresse");
            etuseremail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            etuserpassword.setError("Passord mangler");
            etuserpassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginUserActivity.this, UserToolActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });


    }
}
```

[image: Firebase]

Comment: I'm having a really hard time translating from your description to the actual code that you're having a problem with. Instead of describing all your steps, can you edit your question to show a [single, standalone snippet of code (and possibly the corresponding database) that allows anyone to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I kinda understood what you are trying to achieve. Please share your structure of the user information that you add from the console. Also, share your user's login activity code you use to login the user with credentials from firebase.

Comment: Hi, added the loginuser code and the info from firebase. The data in database is added in a different app I call Admin. So I paste the same Uid I get from Auth in the database hoping I can link the user with the userinfo.

Comment: I have found a solution for this. So this can be closed.